# DiscordJS - Bot is not removing user's reaction in a DM

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I wrote a help command which is executed by typing `!help` in a channel and the bot is triggered. I made a reaction pagination with [`createReactionCollector()`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) and the bot edits the message with the content I react for. Be aware that the following code is an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It works like a charm when I execute it in a channel and the reaction by a user will also be removed right after. So far so good.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/0QScKRh.gif]

```
msg.channel.send('Page: 1️⃣').then(sentMsg => {
    const pages = ['1️⃣','2️⃣','3️⃣']
    pages.map(emj => sentMsg.react(emj))
    const collector = sentMsg.createReactionCollector((args, user) => {
        return pages.includes(args._emoji.name) && user.id === msg.author.id && !user.bot
    }, { max: Infinity })
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
            case pages[0]: sentMsg.edit('Page: '+pages[0]); break; 
            case pages[1]: sentMsg.edit('Page: '+pages[1]); break;  
            case pages[2]: sentMsg.edit('Page: '+pages[2]); break;    
        }
        reaction.users.remove(user).catch(e => {
            if (e.code == 50013) {
                msg.channel.send('[!] Cannot remove reaction of a user. Insufficient permissions.')
            } else {
                console.error(e)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

**The Problem**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/JiDeu5t.gif]

I wanted it to be sent via DM (Direct Message) with `msg.author.send()`. It still edits the message BUT it's not removing the reaction right after as shown in the GIF above. Instead, I get the following error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot execute action on a DM channel                                                  
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\xampp\htdocs\ht\discord\mihojs_beta\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\R
equestHandler.js:154:13)                                                                                
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)                                 
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\xampp\htdocs\ht\discord\mihojs_beta\node_modules\discord.js\src\res
t\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {                                                                            
  method: 'delete',                                                                                     
  path: '/channels/794019488176799744/messages/796506596003545098/reactions/2%EF%B8%8F%E2%83%A3/36298203
0025424907',                                                                                            
  code: 50003,                                                                                          
  httpStatus: 403                                                                                       
}
```

I know that the [`Collector`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html) object collects data about users who reacted to it and I assume in a DM it doesn't work as it's not a channel and thus not part of the guild/server - am I right? I can't seem to find it in the [guide](https://discordjs.guide), anybody knows a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

In Direct Messages you cannot Delete Messages or Remove Reactions from other Users.

This means that for Direct Messages you have two options around the issue:

- Disabling the Command in Direct Message
- Checking if the Channel is a Direct Message / if you have MANAGE_MESSAGES permission and not removing the Reaction

It is indirectly mentioned in the Guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#removing-reactions) that you need MANAGE_MESSAGES Permissions, wich you do not have in DMs, to remove Reactions from other Users.

Comment: Well that's a shame. As I already thought, a DM isn't a channel and not part of a server and thus no permissions exist. Yes I already worked through the error handling regarding permissions. My code already checks the permissions, I just did not place them in the example to avoid unneccesary code. Anyway, thanks for confirmation.

Comment: If your Question has been solved, please mark an answer as the accepted solution using the Green Tick, that will mark the Question as resolved.

Comment: I know but it didn't solve my issue since there is neither a solution to it nor a possible workaround currently. You merely agreed and confirmed what I assumed. And I thanked you for that but it doesn't solve it at all. I'll leave it open by the time in case when new features come out in future for Discord, we never know.

Comment: You could perhaps use the `messageReactionAdd` event and assign each message that you want users to react to with a unique id such as a uuid to identify which message has been reacted to.

Comment: @Intel I do not think you know what the issue here is!